# Same-origin-policy bypass, how/why does this work?

Tags: html, flash, same-origin-policy

How does the same origin policy work? Am I misunderstanding it?
Say we have a host "videos.test.com"
And "videos.test.com/crossdomain.xml" says:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*.test.com" />
<allow-access-from domain="test.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Could another host "blabla.com" embed a video from videos.test.com in itself? Without an iframe?

As far as I know this shouldn't be possible because of the policy.

But this site somehow seems to bypass that:
http://www.vodu.ch/file/dc/7320160c81b3ed93065dbc7e1885f242/?w=960&h=575

So what is the trick, why does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; `crossdomain.xml` allows a website to tell Flash to bypass SOP for specific domains.

See also [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: So this means that it shouldn't be possible for blabla.com to embed a stream from videos.test.com on their site, right?

Comment: Unless they allow it.

Comment: Okay, so why can this site: http://www.vodu.ch/file/dc/7320160c81b3ed93065dbc7e1885f242/?w=960&h=575 force my browser to stream a file from http://media-b160.firedrive.com ? The crossdomain.xml file doesn't seem to allow requests from the domain. http://media-b160.firedrive.com/crossdomain.xml

Comment: It uses Java, not Flash.

Comment: Wrong, it uses both. But it doesn't really matter. A while ago that site worked with flash only. I think it has something to do with the gkplugin stuff, but how and why does it work?

Comment: They just changed it back, now it uses flash only again. 
They also grab the file from vk.com instead of firedrive.com now.